# "Uncaught TypeError: globalThis.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor" When publishing cloudflare worker

Tags: javascript, webpack, cloudflare-workers

When i run "wrangler dev", it compiles, tries to upload then gives me this error. A similar error arises when using "warngler dev".

```
  Uncaught TypeError: globalThis.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor
    at index.js:4699:11 in checkTypeSupport
    at index.js:4720:38 in ../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/wrangler/node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http-lib/capability.js
    at index.js:15:56 in __init
    at index.js:8501:5 in ../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/wrangler/node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http-lib/request.js
    at index.js:15:56 in __init
    at index.js:8718:5 in node-modules-polyfills:http
    at index.js:15:56 in __init
    at index.js:8822:21 in node-modules-polyfills-commonjs:http
    at index.js:18:51 in __require2
    at index.js:16698:16 in node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js
   [code: 10021]

  
  If you think this is a bug, please open an issue at: https://github.com/cloudflare/workers-sdk/issues/new/choose
```

I am using webpack to compile, and my webpack.config.js is as follows. Webpack will compile fine by itself.

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
var fs = require('fs');


module.exports = {
  target: "node",
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: "worker.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: { 
      // browser/worker polyfills required to replace Node libraries used by the jsC8 SDK
      "url": require.resolve("url"),
      "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
     "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
     "assert": require.resolve("assert/")
    }
  }
};
```

Any help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the Firebase node module isn`t compatible with wranglers. :(

Comment: What led you to believe this? Is it documented somewhere? I'm trying to use a different package and wondering if I have the same problem.

Comment: Workers dont support any of the XML modules bc of some funny thing they do with sandboxing. Cant tell you much more than that tho, you`d have to ask them yourself